# Which Fiscal Year Quarter the given date falls into?

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms, sql-server-2016

Example : 
I have a date 02/11/2019  (which is quarter 4 in FY 2019)
I would like to find out which quarter it falls in for the fiscal year using SQL 
Our fiscal year starts July 1 st

Comment: Do you have a calendar table that contains information about your fiscal year?

Comment: yes we do have a table with all the date calculations based on a date

Comment: If you could post the schema of that table, as a `CREATE TABLE` statement, it might prove useful. Although Gordon's answer will certainly get you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that fiscal year 2021 starts on 2020-07-01, then simply add 6 months to the date and use regular date functions:

```
select year(dateadd(month, 6, datecol )) as fiscal_year,
       quarter(dateadd(month, 6, datecol)) as fiscal_quarter
```

If fiscal year 2020 starts on 2020-07-01, then subtract six months instead of adding 6 months.